# Find in the List of words with letters in certain positions

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, find

I'm doing a *crossword puzzle maker*. The user selects cells for words, and the program compiles a crossword puzzle from the dictionary (all words which can be used in the crossword) - `List<string>`.

I need to find a word (words) in a dictionary which matches given mask (pattern).

**For example**, I need to find all words which match

```
#a###g
```

pattern, i.e. all words of length `6` in the dictionary with `"a"` at index `1` and `"g"` at index `5`

The number of letters and their position are unknown in advance

**How do I realize this?**

Comment: Write some code. When you have problems with your code, come back and ask a question

Comment: If the word list doesn't change, it is relatively large, and many queries need to be made with almost instant response, I suggest to create a dictionary where the keys are letters at positions and values are lists of words that satisfy that letter at that specific index. The number of possible keys is 26^(max len word). To avoid using too much space, you can use references as values to the words. Then the answer to any combination of letters is the conjunction of the values of the keys for those letter index combinations.

Comment: *Let's assume that I have a dictionary stored in the List<string>* - wouldn't that be a `List<Dictionary<...,...>>` then? and to what end?

Comment: @user1984 I'm not sure I'd worry about it right away; I just loaded a million guids into an array and LINQ Where'd them looking for `'a'` at `[1]` and `'b'` at `[5]`; 10 milliseconds including the time needed to ToList for ~ 4000 items

Comment: yeah, right. It needs to be tested if such a thing is necessary or not. Good thing you tested it. @CaiusJard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert word description (`mask`)

```
 #a###g
```

into corresponding *regular expression* pattern:

```
 ^\p{L}a\p{L}{3}g$
```

**Pattern explained:**

```
 ^        - anchor, word beginning
 \p{L}    - arbitrary letter
 a        - letter 'a'
 \p{L}{3} - exactly 3 arbitrary letters
 g        - letter 'g'
 $        - anchor, word ending
```

and then get all words from dictionary which match this pattern:

**Code:**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

private static string[] Variants(string mask, IEnumerable<string> availableWords) {
  Regex regex = new Regex("^" + Regex.Replace(mask, "#*", m => @$"\p{{L}}{{{m.Length}}}") + "$");

  return availableWords
    .Where(word => regex.IsMatch(availableWords))
    .OrderBy(word => word)
    .ToArray();
}
```

**Demo:**

```
string[] allWords = new [] {
  "quick",
  "brown",
  "fox",
  "jump",
  "rating",
  "coding"
  "lazy",
  "paring",
  "fang",
  "dog", 
};

string[] variants = Variants("#a###g", allWords);

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, variants));
```

**Outcome:**

```
paring
rating
```

Comment: @nizhgo: you probably want to have an intelligible UI, and take whatever thebuser enters and translate it dynamically into a regular expression. Relying on your users to come up with Regex gibberish is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to find a word in a list with "a" at index 1 and "g" at index 5, like the following

```
wordList.Where(word => word.Length == 6 && word[1] == 'a' && word[5] == 'g')
```

The length check first will be critical to preventing a crash, unless your words are arranged into different lists by length..

If you mean that you literally will pass `"#a###g"` as the parameter that conveys the search term:

```
var term = "#a###g";
var search = term.Select((c,i) => (Chr:c,Idx:i)).Where(t => t.Chr != '#').ToArray();
var words = wordList.Where(word => word.Length == term.Length && search.All(t => word[t.Idx] == t.Chr));
```

How it works:

- Take "#a###g" and project it to a sequence of the index of the char and the char itself, so `('#', 0),('a', 1),('#', 2),('#', 3),('#', 4),('g', 5)`
- Discard the `'#'`, leaving only `('a', 1),('g', 5)`
- This means "'a' at position 1 and 'g' at 5"
- Search the wordlist demanding that the word length is same as "#a###g", and also that All the search terms match when we "get the char out of the `word` at `Idx` and check it matches the `Chr` in the search term